# Rule "new" unknown in boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: bjam, boost-build, b2

I want to use the rule `new` as shown in some of [the documentation examples](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.extender.overview.targets), but I get the error:

```
ERROR: rule "new" unknown in module "Jamfile<path/to/my/module>"
```

What module should I import to access this rule ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `class` module.

Because `class` is also a language keyword you need to use quotes:

```
import "class" ;
```

then you can use `class.new` in your code